# Add a click event for table row in JavaFX

Tags: mouseclick-event

I created a table view.
I want to do something when click on particular row. not on table.
How to write a code to do something for click event on a table row in **JavaFX**.

Comment: Please, if you already have created some code, add it in your question.

Comment: please do some research before asking: work through a tutorial on how to use TableView (hint: and its cells), search this site and other resources. Then apply what you learned, and when stuck come back with [mcve] demonstrating what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rowFactory` property of your `TableView` to customize each row that you insert in your table. Considering that `Thing` is the class you want to display in a table row, it would give:

```
yourTable.setRowFactory(yourTable -> {
    TableRow<Thing> row = new TableRow<Thing>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Thing item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            // Add your row styling mechanism
        }
    }

    row.setOnMouseClicked(me -> {
        if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) { // Left click
            if (me.getClickCount() == 2) { // Double click
                // Double-left-click action
            }

            if (me.getClickCount() == 1) { // Simple click
                // Simple-left-click action
            }
        }
    });

    return row;
});
```

Comment: the problem with utterly unclear questions is that they are not really answerable ;) In this particular case, the only half-way concrete requirement is _click_ on the row - which I don't see in this answer. The other way round: there's no notion of what _do something_ should be .. so a listener to the selected property and update styling may or may not be related :) Anyway, stick to java naming conventions, please (no underscores).

Comment: @kleopatra You're right, I knew there was little chance that my answer was good :) (the solution is based on a company software I made, which has not the exact same requirement). I'll try an update with only necessary things. Concerning underscores, I seems that JNC enables underscores in variable names, provided that this is not the first character (**Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.**).

Comment: that's a technicality: underscores are _possible_ (just as arbitrary upper-lower-case is possible) - but not conforming to conventions :)

Comment: @kleopatra OK thanks for the precision :) Just out of curiosity, how would you write the left member of the listener?