# JavaFX combine two setRowFactory methods

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I have two events that change the color of a table row. For the first event, the row is highlighted when a new entry appears. For the second event, the row color is set back to default on double click.

This is the row highlighting part:

```
    tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Person>(){
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, item != null && !item.isReadOnce());
        }
    });
```

This is the highlight removing part on double click:

```
    tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (! row.isEmpty()) ) {
                pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, false);
            }
        });
        return row ;
    });
```

I don't fully understand how the row factory works. I get that when a row factory is set, each row is taken one by one and assigned the specified listeners, but I'm not sure what part of the row can be accessed from lambda expression and how. Sadly, the documentation is way over my head.

I've tried combining those two but I get a bunch of errors, probably because one assigns a new row to the `tv` parameter and the other one creates the new row and returns it. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: you can use one rowFactory, create tableRow like you're doing in the first factory but don't return it immediately, add the double click event listener, return the tableRow

Comment: what do I have to call in the first factory instead of `row`, since I am no longer creating the table row inside the expression?

Comment: similarly to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64276082/8556269

Comment: that worked and I also found another solution. thanks for your help!